# Angular 9: Read JSON from HTTP get

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient, angular9

I need to extract just one value of a JSON Data some API provide to me. The thing is that I cannot access to the content inside "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate". Below is my code and what I am trying to accomplish that. In advance, thank you so much!

**JSON DATA**

```
{
"Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
    "1. From_Currency Code": "USD",
    "2. From_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
    "3. To_Currency Code": "NOK",
    "4. To_Currency Name": "Norwegian Krone",
    "5. Exchange Rate": "10.60921000", //Need to obtain just this one
    "6. Last Refreshed": "2020-04-25 18:34:28",
    "7. Time Zone": "UTC",
    "8. Bid Price": "10.60921000",
    "9. Ask Price": "10.61031000"
}
```

}

**INTERFACES**

```
export interface PairDetails {
    'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate': PairDetailed[];
}
export interface PairDetailed {
    '1. From_Currency Code': string;
    '2. From_Currency Name': string;
    '3. To_Currency Code': string;
    '4. To_Currency Name': string;
    '5. Exchange Rate': string;
    '6. Last Refreshed': string;
    '7. Time Zone': string;
    '8. Bid Price': string;
    '9. Ask Price': string;
}
```

**CODE TO GET THE VALUES**

```
 private getExchangeRate(pair1: string, pair2: string) {
    return this.http.get(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=${pair1}&to_currency=${pair2}&apikey=demo`);
  }
this.getExchangeRate(separarDivisas[0], separarDivisas[1]).subscribe((v: PairDetails) => {
          const val = v['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate'];
          Object.values(val).forEach((data) => {
            console.log(data['5. Exchange Rate']);
          });
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in your test data 'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate' is object but in PairDetails it is an array. should it be array in test data also?

Comment: @Radik I was trying to convert the object into an array to access to the values but I could not as well.

Comment: you want to loop an object and when you loop object you need to use the key, value instead of directly accessing the data.

use directly : console.log(val['5. Exchange Rate']); 

or loop over the object with : for(let key in val){
    console.log(key, " : ",val[key])
}

Comment: @ArpitPandey thanks, mate. This one worked for me.

Comment: @GenaroAlbertoCancinoHerrera can you check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e6fahi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check this link [angular9-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e6fahi)

```
 apiService
  .getExchangeRate("hello", "world")
  .pipe(
    map(x => x["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]),
    pluck("5. Exchange Rate")
  )
  .subscribe((v: PairDetails) => {
    console.log(v);        
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, brother. With @Arpit Pandey 's answer could solve it but need this full example for do it better.

Answer (score 0):

example this array in test data should work as expected

```
export interface PairDetails {
    'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate': PairDetailed[];
}
export interface PairDetailed {
    '1. From_Currency Code': string;
    '2. From_Currency Name': string;
    '3. To_Currency Code': string;
    '4. To_Currency Name': string;
    '5. Exchange Rate': string;
    '6. Last Refreshed': string;
    '7. Time Zone': string;
    '8. Bid Price': string;
    '9. Ask Price': string;
}

let test = {
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": [{
        "1. From_Currency Code": "USD",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "NOK",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "Norwegian Krone",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "10.60921000", //Need to obtain just this one
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2020-04-25 18:34:28",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC",
        "8. Bid Price": "10.60921000",
        "9. Ask Price": "10.61031000"
    }]
} as PairDetails;

let key: keyof PairDetails = 'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate';

const values = test[key];
console.log(values);
Object.values(values).forEach((data) => {
     console.log(data['5. Exchange Rate']);
});
```

example link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=38&ssc=4&pln=4&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUwhAhgcwQLhtATgSzDRgF4YByACwQBsaQYB3EXGgE3IG4AoUSEGggB09NAApEydAgCUPbggAeABxaxCUBLgBmKYAhgAFFPlwARBFBM0IMAN7cYTigCUEKGlHyIYAYQCuuLgIYMAAnjAAoorAlChEBi4omuTYxqYWVviCbADaALo8AL4KKmowGlq6%20kYm5pbWCGz2js7kAIxCMABiuCBwAPoBQSHhfiBsCKk4UAREPM4UAExdvf1DgcGhEQByKIjTeIRoC20AzF0AKiAbI9vjk4ezx6dO5AAsVzfDW2N7B9gjvNWm8AKxdaKxeIYGBJFKA57AxbkABsXQAMihoLCENpghBqBwEXMTiCKAB2K7eAwALXAU2JLzJ5AAHF0AEL4ZqGAj6J4k14UACcXQAghAANZGXkMmYC7glQSwCUIMLYFVhEDaWoZBrZWxkchuDxeHw-UYRSFxBKw5JTeRKmCabFkByLABExs81L8mwtURi1phcIQ7uwuTdi2c7s6PT6g3N918E1D2HdAFUAMpmd0AGjJHpWcfWib%20%201TMAzYHwmmamaszpgZgENBQuDzBejFxg11uvwiycmYcrOwA8gBpDtR6OfHvfP33f4V907FiMBBofDxGDjvpgUP56dOd3ggNQm0h4cxgAMQhR16FS3a15feZgAHp3zsEE0nQwQAARlkYAwAAVv42JQJQ%20C2PSnbHmiMCYtibh4kghJXks15YQAtNe7w4UsoIwO0LKYGc7yYEsLJTke7qUj2Pp0vuV7ppcvi0dO7psjAnLcjKV7PneD5Pi%2016cVG7oijA4pSjy%20D6IJt4os%20ZzPq%20ZJFPkCowFiOr1FkNjyHw2IAG4eP4SCkE6SBQLkGqFLw4AQAIwiiGIzp2Q5cjcKOAGgQgwBQEI5k0JZEBiKF4UyEI2gsJEeiUGIYhsMkKAyKQAB8LRRiZrkiCA4ipVYuTkKeVrQokdrkPkPlFHIQA)

Comment: @GenaroAlbertoCancinoHerrera is this "const values = test[key];" array or single object? i test it on typescriptlang.org